# How to hide Chakra UI flex box item when it drops to second row without using @media?

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using Chakra UI's flex box system.

In the flex box, I have a left item and a right item that I want to keep on the same row.

When the screen size is reduced, the right item drops down to the second row.

Is there any method to hide the right item when it drops to the second row.

I dont really want to use @media and add class to handle this.

```
import { Wrap, WrapItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";

type WrapperProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Wrapper: React.FC<WrapperProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Wrap w="full" justify="center" spacing="1rem" py="1rem">
      <WrapItem w="full" maxW="40rem">
        {children && children[0 as keyof typeof children]}
      </WrapItem>
      <WrapItem w="full" maxW="18rem">
        {children && children[1 as keyof typeof children]}
      </WrapItem>
    </Wrap>
  );
};
export default Wrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex instead of wrap and give it width of 100% or any you like, set overflow to hidden and its done.

```
<Flex w="full" overflow="hidden">
  /*rest of your code*/
</Flex>
```